# Adding a break within an anchor tag (Using CMS)

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a website that runs on Wordpress. There is a call to action (CTA) on the front page with contact details for the website business. Within the backend one is prompted to enter an email address and phone number for the call to action.

This is then output in an anchor tag:

```
<a class="front-button" href="mailto:myname@example.com">
                    Tel: 123.456.7891  myname@example.com               </a>
```

This creates a fairly large and intrusive big long button on the home page, where the email and phone number are displayed on one line.

Within the CMS I tried to add a break tag in the actual CTA button input box:

```
myname@example.com <br /> Tel: 123.456.7891
```

This just output the exact same html as above, the `<br />` tag was ignored.

I could hard edit the html within the CMS but have two questions:

1) Is there a way to add the break within the CMS input box for the call to action? I imagined something like the opposite of an escape backslash character that says "No, this is html don't ignore"

2) Does a `<br />` tag even work when nested within an anchor `<a>` tag?

[image: CMS input box]

Comment: Why place the telephone number in the email hyperlink? On devices that support phone calls (mobile, computers with Skype etc) you are going to prevent people from hitting the phone number to initiate a call.

Comment: Good point @Steve Fenton. I guess that amplifies question 1 slightly. Sure, I could hard edit the html but wondered if there'd be a way to add html to the CTA input box. I could then nest the appropriate tags within the CTA input

Comment: The CMS part of the question is tough. My CMS would allow "SHIFT+ ENTER" to add a line break... Or I could switch to source view and the br tag - what CMS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1 - can you get your CMS to accept the line break tag?

Depending on the specific CMS - if it has a visual editor, shift and enter can usually get you a line break. If it allows the HTML source to be edited, that should work although the CMS may be using a crude regex that doesn't understand self-closing tags, so try:

```
<br>
```

As well as the self-closing version.

Question 2 - is a line break allowed in an anchor?

In HTML5, a br element is allowed inside any "phrasing element" and an anchor is a phrasing element - so it is allowable to put a br tag inside an a tag.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve. Just to clarify, I'm talking about editing HTML in the backend of the CMS (Wordpress) not the actual text input for content.
In the theme options you enter site name, tagline and CTA text. This is distinct from the blogging backend where folk enter the website content.
I tried closed and non closed br tag with no joy. As for hard editing the html I'll figure it out, I just hoped their might be a way to add an html tag to the CMS input

Comment: Have also added a screen of the input being referred to

Comment: I assume that WordPress is sanitising the input to prevent HTML injection.

Comment: "Sanitising" the input. I'll use that to ask the question a different way. Thanks for input so far. Accepting due to answer on nested a tag